# K means clusters, would PCA be a better option?

Tags: r, classification, clustering, pca, k-means

I have the data below. I need to use a clustering method to classify them and into categories of "Heterozygotote, Allele 1, Allele 2 and No Call. The values in RFU1 and RFU2 are used to determine the call variable.

Any values in RFU1 and RFU2 that are negative should automatically be classified as No Call. I want to develop my own validation check to check the PCR program calls.

**Data**

```
structure(list(Well = structure(1:96, .Label = c("A01", "A02", 
"A03", "A04", "A05", "A06", "A07", "A08", "A09", "A10", "A11", 
"A12", "B01", "B02", "B03", "B04", "B05", "B06", "B07", "B08", 
"B09", "B10", "B11", "B12", "C01", "C02", "C03", "C04", "C05", 
"C06", "C07", "C08", "C09", "C10", "C11", "C12", "D01", "D02", 
"D03", "D04", "D05", "D06", "D07", "D08", "D09", "D10", "D11", 
"D12", "E01", "E02", "E03", "E04", "E05", "E06", "E07", "E08", 
"E09", "E10", "E11", "E12", "F01", "F02", "F03", "F04", "F05", 
"F06", "F07", "F08", "F09", "F10", "F11", "F12", "G01", "G02", 
"G03", "G04", "G05", "G06", "G07", "G08", "G09", "G10", "G11", 
"G12", "H01", "H02", "H03", "H04", "H05", "H06", "H07", "H08", 
"H09", "H10", "H11", "H12"), class = "factor"), Sample = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    Call = structure(c(4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("Allele 1", 
    "Allele 2", "Heterozygote", "No Call"), class = "factor"), 
    Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Auto", class = "factor"), 
    RFU1 = c(-0.295502405, 0.964070798, 3381.332182, 3532.769062, 
    3431.836843, 3242.966511, 2104.791167, 2220.008503, 3548.252161, 
    3506.51418, 2290.273178, 2281.587684, -5.64819475, -11.73109864, 
    3784.914039, 3619.00781, 3618.211608, 3248.106466, 3394.650325, 
    3339.870196, 2449.202902, 2426.835174, 3432.153478, 2761.392304, 
    -9.267907504, -7.365704356, 3743.092314, 3787.241702, 2172.027787, 
    2096.845649, 2135.649551, 2149.145547, 2293.757257, 2348.099108, 
    2321.019045, 2022.168867, -17.93532331, -12.59832941, 3805.416768, 
    3498.998138, 2304.597239, 2509.63987, 2181.11547, 2261.011876, 
    3432.453036, 3662.758933, 2371.11049, 3068.827061, 2612.107589, 
    2687.824075, 3179.315918, 3688.525218, 3465.327523, 3405.154043, 
    2535.514915, 2452.200079, 374.435299, 423.6015308, 3742.515563, 
    3578.777925, 2634.955017, 2527.514043, 3817.579252, 3550.999412, 
    -10.72035816, 3294.486334, 3352.40368, 3463.150507, 3472.576514, 
    3741.898759, 3571.369947, 3720.645869, 3739.569593, 3855.583168, 
    418.6837047, 49.47548241, 2171.034284, 2155.314713, 3432.363384, 
    3582.508917, 3425.415274, 3487.203299, 3505.23909, 3413.342096, 
    113.5100691, 128.6414053, 2454.588175, 2323.061591, 3188.705702, 
    3376.950546, 3291.072437, 3181.001961, 3195.013863, 3776.919197, 
    2284.22659, 2277.338631), RFU2 = c(-8.346468029, 235.4058561, 
    637.9218251, 650.3759507, 617.4161748, 604.0792911, 4270.310727, 
    4199.615749, 689.863543, 712.6144338, 4274.287194, 4541.168491, 
    -1.626221758, -2.437395631, 802.0941252, 730.5998997, 686.9037384, 
    625.8245403, 644.3586836, 642.8833044, 4937.691887, 5159.479928, 
    725.4449756, 573.3910899, -4.006398006, 213.2859144, 739.7910786, 
    731.0150586, 4408.81923, 4767.533969, 4302.641493, 4325.913445, 
    4597.47663, 4666.904418, 4800.357526, 4142.535329, -17.23239968, 
    178.5311942, 778.305843, 743.1438168, 4214.507094, 4553.703511, 
    4629.339014, 4459.697405, 661.7299014, 727.1054982, 4553.170272, 
    5482.231486, 4520.517999, 4737.802036, 643.3599887, 726.4314715, 
    696.5968338, 697.6099599, 411.8118071, 409.4943424, 5687.32635, 
    5757.51512, 766.4240193, 779.2403225, 4745.055632, 4582.267792, 
    749.5679421, 675.8747055, -7.254521898, 628.3467565, 631.116767, 
    672.7064514, 687.2642132, 718.1192917, 731.785499, 668.3686048, 
    784.8055727, 791.3155894, 4471.047168, 4501.597841, 4504.670332, 
    4442.621066, 682.0632225, 706.6204595, 680.5242182, 683.9558692, 
    684.2909706, 618.6535251, 5727.684954, 6098.485474, 5099.952926, 
    4779.742057, 571.4303822, 614.9258218, 602.9830491, 651.2847695, 
    591.8833499, 742.2387568, 4443.376841, 4716.792177)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-96L))
```

**What I have tried so far**

```
library(cluster)
library(factoextra)
library(formattable)

df <- df[,c(1,5,6)]
df$RFU1[df$RFU1 < 0] <- 0
df$RFU2[df$RFU2 < 0] <- 0
df$RFU1 <- formattable(df$RFU1, digits = 2, format = "f")
df$RFU2 <- formattable(df$RFU2, digits = 2, format = "f")
df$Well <- as.numeric(df$Well)


clusters <- kmeans(df, centers = 4)
Kmeans_plot <- fviz_cluster(clusters, data = df)
```

**This is the plot generated**
[image]

Points in the top right 57,58,75,76,85,86 should be in another cluster (classed as allele 2 but placed in cluster 1 (rest of points in this cluster are heterozygote)

Also points 24, 55, 56 should be clustered with cluster 2 as all these points are classed as allele 1

**I need an algorithm that can detect optimal cluster center, some PCR runs may only have 3 different call variables instead of 4**

Comment: You may want to ask this on https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/